What is the step-by-step process to solve Angle = ArcCos(R / R+h)?
I'm attempting to calculate the angle to the horizon from various heights to determine how much of the Earth's curve should actually be observable; however, every example and website I've seen that shows the formula doesn't actually show the steps you go through to solve the problem.
I.E. On one post, someone calculated the angle to the horizon from 40,000-feet to be about 3.54-degrees; however, when I do:
20,903,520(radius of Earth in feet) / 20,943,520(Radius + height) 

I get 0.998, which when put into ArcCos gives me 0.06.
Is this correct and if not, then what am I doing wrong?
The same person whose calculations I saw somehow came up with the formula
1.5924 + 0.048892 * (h / 1000)

But I have no idea where the 1.5924 or 0.048892 came from. Does anyone else know?

Have you heard of the GIS tool Viewshed? It creates a raster based on a DEM (coarse raster data is free to download) that indicates what can be seen from a given observer point? Please indicate what GIS software you are using or this question will likely be closed as having no clear GIS component.

I'm not using any GIS component. I'm using math. So, I'm not allowed to ask questions unless I'm using some nonsense from this site in particular?

0.06 is the answer in radians - here's the calculation using R:
> acos(20903520/(20903520+40000))
[1] 0.06181435

One radian is about 57 degrees, or exactly 180 divided by pi. So convert to degrees by multiplying by 180/pi:
> (180/pi)*acos(20903520/(20903520+40000))
[1] 3.541701

which is your 3.54 degrees.
The documentation for your arccos function in your software should say if it returns radians or degrees, but if you are getting 0.06 for something you expect to be 3.54, its returning radians.
The other formula you give looks like a linear approximation to the arccos solution that might only be correct for a small range of h values. Again using R I can plot the output value of the angle against the altitude over a range of altitudes.

The red line is the arccos solution, the blue is the formula at the end of your post. Its off by about 1.5 degrees for low altitudes, but is pretty close from 15,000 to 50,000 feet, possibly within the error due to the spherical earth approximation when compared to a real world earth will its ellipsoidal nature and its lumps and bumps and atmospheric distortion to the horizon and the fact that the earth is really flat j/k.
That linear approximation could have been devised from the arccos exact solution in a number of ways, and it may have been done to save a primitive flight computer (which might just have been a few gears and cogs) having to work out the complexity of the arccos function within the operating range of the flight.

Thank you. This is the answer. The other person neglected to say the answer would be in radians and so would have to be converted to degrees.
